# How to remove silence at the beginning and end of a file with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Some earlier threads said that the silenceremove filter doesn't support trimming silence from the end? is this still the case?

My audio is lossless so I don't need to streamcopy or anything fancy like that.

Also how do I set it up to cut "silence" less than 96dB?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a python script that does exactly that:

- it reads all m4a files from a folder called input
- removes silence from beginning and end
- outputs the files to output

Source:

```
import os
temp1 = "temp1.m4a"
temp2 = "temp2.m4a"
temp3 = "temp3.m4a"
all_files = [x for x in os.listdir("input/")]
for file in all_files:
  if file.endswith(".m4a"):
    print os.popen("ffmpeg -i long/" + file + " -af silenceremove=1:0:-96dB " + temp1).read()
    print os.popen("ffmpeg -i " + temp1 + " -af areverse " + temp2).read()
    print os.popen("ffmpeg -i " + temp2 + " -af silenceremove=1:0:-96dB " + temp3).read()
    print os.popen("ffmpeg -i " + temp3 + " -af areverse output/" + file).read()
    os.remove(temp1)
    os.remove(temp2)
    os.remove(temp3)
```

Answer (score 4):

With version 4.1.3 still can't trim from end.

Workaround:

```sh
ffmpeg -i IN.WAV -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-96dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-96dB,areverse OUT.WAV
```

Comment: With version 4.4.1, this still doesn't work - `silenceremove` with positive `stop_periods` value appears to remove arbitrary audio sections from the middle of audio.